# function acos in sql fail in some case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to used `acos` function but it give me fail. I tried to make code easier understand like this.

```
select 10.800887 Latitude, 106.710729 Longitude into #tam
declare @latitude float  = 10.800887,
@longitude float  = 106.710729

select acos(xx) as result  from(
select 
    sin((@latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((cast(Latitude as float)*pi()/180))+cos((@latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((cast(Latitude as float)*pi()/180)) * cos(((@longitude - cast(Longitude as float))*pi()/180)) as xx
 from #tam
 ) a
 drop table #tam
```

Error

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

But when you put

```
select acos(1)
```

The function give result 0. What problem with acos(xx) in first code result?

Comment: Select acos(1) result is 0, but select  acos(xx) above give me error: An invalid floating point operation occurred.

Comment: You are aware that SQL Server has a built-in geography data type, aren't you? If so, why are you ignoring it here?

Answer (score 1):

> An expression of either type float or of a type that can implicitly
>   convert to float. Only a value ranging from -1.00 to 1.00 is valid.
>   Values outside this range return NULL, and ASIN will report a domain
>   error.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/acos-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Evidently that is not what actually happens.

Comment: select acos(2);  Result: An invalid floating point operation occurred.

Comment: The fact that the documentation apparently isn't even aware of what function it's documenting (`ASIN`???) would indicate that this documentation isn't to a particularly high standard.

Comment: I agree with you. But still, the problem is in a value that is not in the range from -1 to 1.

Comment: I have submitted a documentation bug report on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast to `DECIMAL(9,2)` as your valid range of `ACOS` is from `-1.00 to 1.00`:

```
select 10.800887 Latitude, 106.710729 Longitude into #tam
declare @latitude float  = 10.800887,
@longitude float  = 106.710729

select acos(CAST(xx AS decimal(9,2))) as result  from(
select 
    sin((@latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((cast(Latitude as float)*pi()/180))+cos((@latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((cast(Latitude as float)*pi()/180)) * cos(((@longitude - cast(Longitude as float))*pi()/180)) as xx
 from #tam
 ) a
 drop table #tam
```

Even the `SELECT` returns `0`, the data type is `float` and the engine might think that it may contain more digits then the allowed.

Comment: `DECIMAL(9,2)` is arbitrary, and it is not about number of allowed digits. Try `select acos(2)`.

Comment: GSerg, why to try 2 when the range is from `-1.00 to 1.00`? The whole point is the engine is thinking we are going to pass something that is not in this range.

Comment: `2` is because it is one digit, and you are talking about number of allowed digits. Casting to `DECIMAL(9,2)` is wrong too as it will only work for this particular value of `xx` (`1.00020885695825`). If `xx` was `1.005`, your code would result in the same error.

Comment: @GSerg Right, but in that case, it will mean there is something wrong with the input parameters and I am no trying to validate the input parameters - I am trying to tell the engine the data is in the correct format and it is safe to evaluate it.

Comment: There is no formatting problem. The value will be converted to `float` before it reaches `acos`. The entire issue is about the value of the number, not about its textual representation. The `An invalid floating point operation occurred` comes from inside of `acos`, after the value has successfully been converted to a valid `float`.

Comment: I think the issue is that the engine is expecting that incorrect number is going to be returned - and an error is thrown, before the value is calculated at all.